# Redirect to login when logout is succeded Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to be able to redirect to login when I log out of my app.I cannot find any solution , i am just stuck with the message:"You are logged out".
[You are logged out message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa0Dn.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're implementing your authentication mechanism, but you can inject `NavigationManager` into the class that has access to the auth states, and then call the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` function to redirect the user.

Have a look at this Microsoft page for [dependency injection in Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly), and [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#uri-and-navigation-state-helpers-1) for `NavigationManager`.